# Calling a Powershell script from Batch script..But need the batch script to wait for the Powershell script to complete

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch script being that has the following code in it:

Here is the batch script (Test.bat):

```
call powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1

exit /b
```

The Powershell script (TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1) has some wait built into it. But when this file is being called, the batch script is NOT waiting for the Powershell script to finish.

I ever tried:

```
START /wait powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1
```

To no effect.

When I double click on the Test.bat file, it seems to be waiting. I have checked out a lot of answers, but couldnt find any that correspond to this issue.

Please help.

Comment: Don't use the `CALL` or `START` commands.  They are not needed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use timout, pause, or Choice /T xxx /C /N yn /D n /M "Y/N"?

Comment: @Squashman, thank you for your reply, will try it out now and post my results.

Comment: @T3RR0R, we have all our logic in Powershell, but just use batch files to simply call them, as a company standard for Powershell scripts.

Comment: Sure, but with Choice /T or timeout, You can proceed to a function to test if the powershell script is still active, meaning no Direct user interaction is necessary. I'm assuming these batch are running silent with something along the lines of vbscript? vbs could also be used to monitor the process state for powershell and call another silent batch to forcefeed input into the main batch to continue once the powershell scipt is closed.

Comment: @Squashman, still no luck.

Comment: @T3RR0R, thank you for your reply, I was hoping I could achieve it directly with just some standard options from batch scripting, but sounds like that is the route I will have to take if there are no other options.

Comment: @Number10, I don't know what to tell you.  Where I work we have dozens of batch files that also run PowerShell scripts and do not see the same behavior when executing PowerShell.exe directly.

Comment: I executed your original code as `powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1`. The only thing I put in the Powershell was, a sleep cmdlet for 10 seconds.  I then put a pause in the batch file after the powershell.  If your theory is true I should see the output from the pause command before the sleep from the powershell finishes but I did not. The pause did not execute until the 10 seconds from the powershell sleep was done.

Comment: Start /wait will [with no other modifcations before or after] hold the batch, however, depending on how the script exits, results in a Terminate batch Job prompt - as opposed to reliably continuing other batch commands without interaction.

Comment: @Squashman, the script runs absolutely perfect when ran stand alone, i.e, it absolutely waits for the Powershell script to complete before moving on as I mentioned above. However, we call the Test.bat script from our Mainframe job scheduler (Stonebranch) and the same exact batch script there doesn't wait for the Powershell script to finish, it basically exits out as soon as it calls the process weirdly!

Comment: So I ended up coding a fix around it, for the Powershell script to spit out an output file on completion of its execution and the batch script ends up looking for the file and if not found, it waits a couple of minutes and checks again until it finds it. Which is exactly what I was trying to avoid and was hoping there was a really easy way of waiting for the PS script to finish.

Comment: Regardless of the new information  you have provided, cmd.exe is not going to behave any differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
start /wait powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1 | ECHO > nul
```

Try the above. Holds the command until scripts executed, without the Teminate Batch Prompt. Use start /min /wait if not needing to display or interact with the script, or Alternately:

```
start /wait powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -WindowStyle Hidden -File TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1 | ECHO > nul

-WindowStyle Value
Sets the window style for the session. Valid values are Normal, Minimized, Maximized and Hidden.
```

*** | *** pipes the output of the command, however as your just starting powershell.exe and not using it in the context of utilizing a command like follows, It shouldn't be an issue.

```
powershell -command "((Get-date).AddDays(0)).ToString(':dd:MM:yyyy') | set-content 'captureVar.txt'" && set /p Yesterday=<captureVar.txt
```

It worked for the script I tested, but it's not thoroughly tested.
let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried the above 2 options before and as I mentioned, they run fine stand alone, as in, when I double click on the .bat file, it absolutely waits for the Powershell script to complete before moving on, however, we call the Test.bat script from our Mainframe job scheduler (Stonebranch) and the same exact batch script there doesn't wait for the Powershell script to finish, it basically exits out as soon as it calls the process weirdly!

Comment: So I ended up coding a fix around it, for the Powershell script to spit out an output file on completion of its execution and the batch script ends up looking for the file and if not found, it waits a couple of minutes and checks again until it finds it. Which is exactly what I was trying to avoid and was hoping there was a really easy way of waiting for the PS script to finish.

Comment: I've just tested the same by throwing a Call to the batch launching ps1 from a batch on a usb, and it was a disaster of sorts. Not only did the batch not wait, the powershell  script did no execute properly. 

I'll have to research Call behaviour from non local directories to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command ". 'C:\path\TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1'"
```

This should do the it, if not then we will add `< NUL` to the end

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command ". 'C:\path\TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1'" < NUL
```

By using dot sourcing, we are opening powershell in the cmd window with the `powershell` reference in the above solution. Then the period allows the script to run in cmd window also. I did a double test and made a .ps1 with `start-sleep -s 3` in it, and the above did wait for the powershell script to finish.

**method 2**
Using `Start /wait`

```
START /wait PowerShell.exe "& "'C:\path\TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1'"
```

This method will not run inside the cmd window. It opens a powershell terminal and runs there then goes back to the bat.

Comment: Thanks Shadoe2020, the issue is that I need the batch script to wait for the Powershell script to finish before moving along, which happens to work totally fine standalone but when called from our job scheduler, it just calls the Powershell script and moves along.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more likely to be within "TheScriptToBeExecuted.ps1" than your bat. In fact several powershell command are working as Asyncronous.
I tested a Sleep-Start, which is not Asyncronous at all using the following code and the bat is waiting the end of it.
This is the code I used in my .bat

```
REM RUNTEST.BAT
time /T
echo started
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\DA_PROVARE\test.ps1
time /T
echo done
exit /b
```

The ps1 content is just one row, here below:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is probably because of the account under which the scheduler runs. Have faced similar problems where the .bat and/or .ps1 doesn't behave the same if launched by a scheduler or other tools